# Show images in Joomla 3.10 search results (com_search)

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, images, search, com-search

I want to show the intro image of articles in Joomla 3.10 search results (com_search).

In previous Joomla 3 versions, I know that you could do this:

1. Create template override:

   ```
   /templa tes/template_name/html/com_search/search/default_results.php
   ```
2. Then get access to the images using this code:

   ```
   $images = json_decode($result->images);
   ```

Now I see in Joomla 3.10 that `$result` only has these values:

```
[relevance] => 
[title] => 
[metadesc] => 
[metakey] => 
[created] => 
[language] => 
[catid] => 
[text] => 
[section] => 
[slug] => 
[catslug] => 
[browsernav] => 
[href] => 
[jcfields] => 
[count] =>
```

Is there any way to get access to article images?

Answer (score 1):

The search component (com_search) gets its results from search plugin and it returns precomputed data of article's most needed parts.

I can give you just a quick example how you could fetch article but it may affect the overall performance, because you're going to load them one by one.

**The first method via the JTable:**

```
$article = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
$article->load(array('id'=>$result->slug)); 
$images = json_decode($article->images);
```

**The second method via the JModelLegacy**

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true)); 
$model->setState('params', JApplication::getInstance('site')->getParams()); 
$article = $model->getItem($result->slug);
$images = json_decode($article->images);
```

In case of JTable you can provide array of slugs and fetch many articles, but you need to parse $results variable in your template override.
Mind that the code I've presented has no checks at all, but it builds basic playground to start with.

Comment: Hey, thanks, JTable method works. And any idea, how to get an image from a Contact, instead of Article?

Comment: Same way with minor upgrade.

`JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_contact/tables');
$table = JTable::getInstance('Contact', 'ContactTable');
$table->load(array('id'=>$result->slug)); 
var_dump($table->image);`

Comment: Thanks, it also works!